# Laravel Mix: Using Mix() to cache bust around another helper

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I have a helper defined below:

```
function cdn($file)
{
    return env('CDN_URI', '').'/'.ltrim($file, '/');
}
```

In my blade, I am serving the bundled Vue js file with the helper:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ cdn('/dist/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

I am having caching issues now so I want to start using versioning.  I read in Laravel Mix docs that to imoport the versioned files, put them in the `mix()` .  Would I be able to wrap that around my other helper as follows:

````
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ mix(cdn('/dist/js/app.js')) }}"></script>```
````

Comment: Of course you would. All `cdn` is doing is making a string.

Answer (score 1):

To enable versioning, you need to add the following in your `webpack.mix.js` when you are compiling your assets.

`mix.version();`

Something along the lines of:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .version();
```

Then after you add this to your template:

```js
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Compile your assets with `npm run prod,` and if you view the source, you will see something like the following where you put your JavaScript.

```js
<script src="/js/app.js?id=476befa31a13c804b084"></script>
```

Finally, you can add your `cdn()` helper, make sure to wrap the helper around the `mix()` function.

```js
<script src="{{ cdn(mix('js/app.js')) }}"></script>
```